--local-gateway2: command not found - AzureCLI
I am trying to create a VPN-connection via AzureCLI but only --local-gateway2 is giving error below:

According to official Microsoft documentation, this should be correct:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/vpn-connection?view=azure-cli-latest

stages:
  - stage: Deploy_VPN_Connection
    jobs:
    - job: Create_IPSec_VPN_Connection
      continueOnError: false
      steps:
        - task: AzureCLI@2
          displayName: 'Create_IPSec_VPN_Connection'
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '$(ServiceConnectionName)' # Use Service Connection to deploy the code to Azure.
            ScriptType: 'bash'
            scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
            InlineScript: |                                     # Powershell Inline commands

              # Select Subscription to use
              az account set --subscription '$(SubscriptionName)'

              # Retrieve the shared key from Key Vault
              # SHARED_KEY=$(az keyvault secret show --vault-name '($KeyVaultName)' --name '($SecretName)' --query value -o tsv)

              # Deploy IPsec VPN Site-to-Site in Azure
              az network vpn-connection create \
                --name '($VPNConnectionName)' \
                --resource-group '($ResourceGroupName)' \
                --location '($Location)' \
                --vnet-gateway1 '($VNetGatewayName)' \
                --shared-key 'TEST123!' \
                --local-gateway2 '($LocalNetworkGatewayName)'


If your pipeline was designed to reference the variables defined in your pipeline variables section or library of variable group(s) to run Azure CLI commands, it should probably use $(var) instead of ($var). Please try running the script below to make sure the variables defined in or linked to your pipeline is expanded as expected.
az network vpn-connection create \
  --name '$(VPNConnectionName)' \
  --resource-group '$(ResourceGroupName)' \
  --location '$(Location)' \
  --vnet-gateway1 '$(VNetGatewayName)' \
  --shared-key 'TEST123!' \
  --local-gateway2 '$(LocalNetworkGatewayName)'


I guess that was the issue. I used to do pipelines via Powershell but this resolved it. Thank you Alvin!

Glad to know the variable syntax tip helps. Happy coding and cheers!
